# MySQL: merge different tables into one big table

Tags: mysql, copy

I have 12 tables with this 2 fields:

- **code** (varchar primary key) and **text** (varchar)

Each table has already 1055 entries (all tables have the same amount then)

I need to make a new table with the following fields:

- **id** (int pk), **field-1**, **field-2**, ... **field-2**

Each **field-N** will have the contents of the **text** field of one of the tables. I don't need the **code** field from those tables.

So, at the end, this new big table should have 1055 entries, with the **id** field going from 1 to 1055, and the rest of fields (**field-1**, **field-2**, etc) storing the values held in the **text** field of the 12 tables that I have now.

How can I accomplish this? I've been trying for a while but I can't find the right way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how do you match the text fields from table1 with the text fields from table2? They have the same code?

Comment: no, the code field in the 12 tables is different. The new "big" table that I want now is empty, I just want to fill it up with the contents of the 12 tables

Comment: That table design is really bad, why did you need 12 tables which all have the same attributes?

Comment: yes sure but how can you tell row1 from table1 goes with row1 from table2? How do you define that a row actually is the row1?

Comment: sorry, I know the table design is bad, it was like that when I got this task

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question but I would simply write a loop that will insert each row of each table into a newly created table.

Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
(
code int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
text varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (code)
)
```

// Do this for each table:

```
SELECT text FROM table1;

for(int i = 0; i < dataSet.size; i++)
{
  INSERT INTO newTable (text) VALUES (row(i).value)
}
```

Comment: If I understand him correctly, your answer is missing half the requirement, he needs to dynamically add the 1055 different columns that he's referring to.

Comment: I think he has 12 tables each with 2 columns - column1 = Code and column2 = text. If you create a table and set code as the primary key to autoincrement, then select all entries from each of the 12 tables and insert them into the new table, the autoincrement will dynamically extend the table and he doesn't say anything about the order of the text fields so it should work fine. In the end you will have a single table with 1055 tuples.

Comment: You could be right, sorry...he had another question about adding 10 million columns, so I might be mixing the two questions.

Comment: @ewein can I do what you say in your last comment just fom phpMyAdmin? What you say is what I need to do, select all the entries of the **text** field of one table and insert them, in the same order, in the field that I want in that second table. How do I do this?

Comment: I have only used phpMyAdmin very briefly so I can't help you there. But it would be much faster to write a small script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

So what I finally decided to do is to download all the information of those tables to excel, create a new excel with the structure and values that I needed, and upload this new excel as CSV. Now I have exactly what I wanted! Probably not the best method, but it didn't take so long and worked :)